# Lambda Calculus: build a function that takes more arguments with each iteration

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm trying to build a function that takes a given number of arguments and always return the same value.

This is a part of an homework. There is a hint provided:

> The "k-way T" is a function that takes k arguments and always returns T. A "0-way T" is just T.

Where k is provided as Church Numeral and T is the lambda expression for True (\x.\y.x).

The complete task is to provide an lambda expression that computes an k-way OR function. Where the number of 'boolean' arguments is provided before the 'boolean' arguments. e.g:

```
((OR 3) F T F)
```

But for now I'm trying to create that takes *k* arguments and returns always *T*. The *k* is provided as first argument.

```
((TRUE 2) T F) == T
```

So basically I wan't to create a function that has one more argument for each church numeral 'iteration'.

But somehow I'm completely stuck.

Can I do that with only an church numeral? Or do I need recursion (Y-Combinator)?

In general: Are there any good tools (e.g for visualization) that support the creation of lambda expressions.

I'm really astonished about the power of the lambda calculus and I really want to learn it. But I don't know how...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll show how to implement the `TRUE` function.
Since `k` is not fixed, you need a fixed-point combinator (`Y` would do, but it's not the only fixed-point combinator).
First of all a couple words about the notation I've used below: `iszero` (takes a Church numeral, checks if it is Church zero and returns a Church boolean), `T` (the Church-encoded true boolean value), `pred` (the predecessor function for Church numerals), and `Y` (a fixed-point combinator).

```
let TRUE = Y (λr. λn. (iszero n) T (λx. (r (pred n))))
```

Notice that `let` is not part of lambda calculus syntax, it's metasyntax to introduce a name (for us).

This works as follows: `Y` *sort of* converts the `r` argument into "self" -- when a function calls `r` it calls itself. To illustrate this, I'm going to rewrite the above into recursive form (warning: it's for illustrative purposes only, lambda calculus **does not allow** this; since all the functions are anonymous you can't call them using their names -- there is just no way for this):

```
let TRUE = λn. (iszero n) T (λx. (TRUE (pred n)))
```

I've stripped off the `λr.` part and replaced `r` by `TRUE` (again, please do not do this in your homework, it is not valid lambda calculus).

And this definition is easier to understand: if `TRUE` is called like this `TRUE 0` it just returns `T`, otherwise it returns a function of one argument which wraps around a function of (n - 1) arguments, essentially representing a function of n arguments.

As for your question on tools: one way would be to use Scheme/Racket -- it would help checking your "lambda calculus code" runs as it should. For example, here is an implementation of `TRUE` in Racket:

```
(define (Y f)
  ((lambda (x) (x x))
   (lambda (x) (lambda (a) ((f (x x)) a)))))

(define TRUE
  (Y (lambda (r)
       (lambda (n)
         (if (zero? n)
             #t
             (lambda (x) (r (sub1 n))))))))

;; tests
> (TRUE 0)
#t
> ((TRUE 1) #f)
#t
> (((TRUE 2) #f) #f)
#t
> ((((((TRUE 5) #f) #f) #f) #f) #f)
#t
```

I ought to add that I used here built-in booleans, integers, if-expression, `sub1`, `zero?` instead of Church-encoded ones. Otherwise it would make this example much bigger (or incomplete).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still need to figure it out. But I think I'll manage with your explanation...

Comment: Thank you I now understand the k-way TRUE and managed to implement it. I had already a look at Scheme and tried to follow the MIT Scheme course (it's somewhat old but I think it's still a very good introduction to functional programming and CS in general).

Comment: Now I'm stuck with the k-way OR. I try to create a function that creates a n-way T and an n-way OR for each iteration n (from 0 to k). Starting with  p_0 = (T_0, F_0), p_1 = (T_1, (OR F_0)), ..., p_n =(T_n, (OR F_n-1)), ... But I'm stuck again. The T_n is created with the k-way-T function (see original question). The k-way-OR is created like this: IF arg THEN k-1-way-T else k-1-way-OR (and ignore the argument). But it doesn't work. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first part of your comment, but "IF arg THEN k-1-way-T else k-1-way-OR" sounds like you're on the right track. Some  hints: (1) you need Y combinator again, (2) you need to check for zero argument case (OR should be false, since it is true iff at least one arg is true); (3) don't forget to wrap non-zero branch in a lambda: "IF arg ..." should be "λarg. IF arg ...".

Comment: So i took a different aproach than i wrote in my last comment. Now I have someting like (Y (λg n. (IF k=0 THEN FALSE ELSE (λnext_bool. (IF next_bool THEN k-way-TRUE (-- n) ELSE ((g g) (-- n))))))). It's a big mess and I get a infinite recursion (at least it seams so since it doesn't stop. How cn I debug such a thing? Our exercise system prints the reduction steps. But I get totally lost follwing each step...

Comment: It's almost right. (1) I guess it's a typo: "IF k=0", it should be 'n', not 'k'. (2) Instead of '(g g)' use just 'g' -- Y will take care of it. It's one of Y's duties -- you could write your recursive function without Y, you could pass the function to itself as an argument (yes, you would have to right the body twice), and then the right way to use it recursively would be always passing it to itself, just like you did: '(f f)'. But using Y you don't have to do it. Use 'g' as a normal name of a recursive function - it will work.

Comment: I fixed the (f f) isue. And I had an error in a decrement function. At last I found a renaming bug. Missed a boud variable when renaming.... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're welcome! In my previous comment "have to right the body twice" = "have to write the body twice" [it's for the future readers :)]

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on that exact homework right now, and I just wanted to tell you and any future readers that a fixed-point combinator is absolutely not needed for this.

To get from the pair `Pk:=(k-way T, k-way OR)` to the pair `Pk+1:=(k+1-way T, k+1-way OR`, you simply apply the function `lambda Pk. (lambda a b c. c a b) (lambda arg. Pk (lambda x y. x)) (lambda arg. Pk arg)`.

In a nutshell, this function deconstructs your pair and constructs a new pair, eating one more argument. The new `k+1-way OR` is simply just the `k-way OR` from `Pk`in case the argument is `F` or a `k-way T` in case the argument is `T`.

The only thing you need to do now that you have this function, is to apply it n times to the starting pair `P0:=(lambda a b c. c a b) (lambda x y. x) (lambda x y. y)`, which you can do using the Church numeral n. In the end you only need to take the second part of this pair and you should be left with an `n-way OR`.

Comment: I'm so glad I found this answer. Sadly I still cannot get it to work. I'm putting together your proposed pieces wrongly. Could you maybe elaborate on that?

Comment: Maybe you're missing the parts of how to construct pairs and access the elements of a pair: A pair can be constructed using the function "pair" which is defined as ``pair= lambda a b c. c a b``. The elements of a pair can be accessed using the function "first" which is defined just like T, and the function "second" which is defined just like F.


My starting pair P0 is the pair (T, F), because the 0-way T is equal to T, and the 0-way OR is equal to F.

Applying the iteration function f should be easy using the church numeral n, as you should be able to give f and P0 as arguments.

Comment: This should return you the pair Pn, and then doing ``second Pn`` is your n-way OR function.